# jQuery animate() doesn't correctly animate height the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have built a toggle that will slide down a div to reveal content. I am not using the normal `toggle()` function of `jQuery` because I wanted to show the top 300px of content and then slide to reveal the rest.

Anyways, I have a script setup that animates the height of the container div, which reveals the content inside.

```
function slideCut() {

    var revertHeight = 300;
    var finalHeight = 0;
    var s = 1000;

    $('.cutBottom a').click(function() {

        event.stopPropagation();
        var p = $(this).parent().parent();
        var h = p.css('height', 'auto').height();
        var cut = $(this).parent().find('.cutRepeat');

        // Fix height
        if (finalHeight == 0) {
            p.css('height', 'auto');
            finalHeight = p.height();
            p.height(revertHeight);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
            $(this).removeClass('toggled');
            p.animate({height:revertHeight}, {
                duration: s
            });
            cut.fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('toggled');
            p.animate({height:finalHeight}, {
                duration: s,
                complete: function() {
                    cut.fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

}//end
```

**The problem is, the second time it animates the height to the full size (sliding the div to reveal content) it does not animate, it just jumps to the full height. Why is this happening?**

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6xp2Y/3/**

Comment: I've run into this before - ended up using `slideToggle` in combination with `stop()` to limit the height. I'll try and get it working in your fiddle for you!

Comment: Of course, jsfiddle is DOWN right now :@

Comment: Yeah, just noticed this too. Getting a 500 error from one of their scripts.

Comment: Fixed - just had to remove one line. See updated answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all that hard work and fiddle being broken, all we had to do was remove one line from your code:

```
function slideCut() {

    var revertHeight = 300;
    var finalHeight = 0;
    var s = 1000;

    $('.cutBottom a').click(function() {

        event.stopPropagation();
        var p = $(this).parent().parent();
        //var h = p.css('height', 'auto').height(); //REMOVE THIS LINE
        var cut = $(this).parent().find('.cutRepeat');

        // Fix height
        if (finalHeight == 0) {
            p.css('height', 'auto');
            finalHeight = p.height();
            p.height(revertHeight);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
            $(this).removeClass('toggled');
            p.animate({height:revertHeight}, {
                duration: s
            });
            cut.fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('toggled');
            p.animate({height:finalHeight}, {
                duration: s,
                complete: function() {
                    cut.fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

}//end

slideCut();
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/6xp2Y/5/

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work at all. Hides all the content.

Comment: aw boo! OK, I'll update this once fiddle is working again with a *hopefully* working answer.

Comment: Ha, that worked! Thanks man. Had not realized that I wasn't even using that line.

Comment: Yeah -- you could have removed `, 'auto'` and it would be reading the value, but by adding '`height', 'auto'` you're actually setting the value ^_^ glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer!

The proplem lies here

```
if (finalHeight == 0) {
  parent.css('height', 'auto');
  finalHeight = parent.height();
  parent.height(revertHeight);
  console.log('finalHeight:'+finalHeight);
}
```

This is only running at the beginning, because `finalHeight` is not `0` anymore after first run.

You can fix this by setting `finalHeight` back to `0` after closing it again, like so

```
if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
  $(this).removeClass('toggled');
  parent.animate({height:revertHeight}, {
    duration: speed
  });
  cut.fadeIn('fast');
  finalHeight = 0;
} else { [...]
```

Comment: Using any of the build in `slide` methods won't work for me. They all hide the element after it slides up. I do not want this. As I said in my description, I show the top 300px of content as a preview of it. Using the `jQuery slide()` methods would hide this too.